# Integral as a limit of sum: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac k{n^2+n+2k}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

> The value of$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac k{n^2+n+2k}\right)=\,?$$

Can the limit be partially applied to the denominator after converting the numerator into an integral?
I wrote this as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac {k/n}{1+1/n+2k/n^2}\right)$$
From what I know I can write that $1/n$ as $\mathrm{d}x$ and $k/n$ as $x$. Can I apply limit to denominator as $n$ tends to infinity and rewrite the denominator as $1$.

Comment: Do not post pictures in questions, they are not indexed by a search engine. Instead use MathJax. Also, always show your work.

Comment: Welcome to the website. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your maths instead of putting pictures. Pictures are not searchable, may be removed from the hosting site and are not readable by screen-readers, thus should not constitute the critical component of your post unless absolutely inevitable.

Comment: Am new....will surely do from next time.....apologies for inconvenience

Comment: @satyam Do it now, not next time.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri thankyou

Comment: Oops, I have done it now. Still, while I suspect the validity of what you are trying to do, it is not possible to give a definitive YES/NO unless you show us your working. It is not very hard to use Mathjax, mostly you have to type normal maths and just enclose it between `$` signs to render it. Like `$x+1$` yields $x+1$, `$x^k$` yields $x^k$,`$\frac{a}{b}$` yields $\frac{a}{b}$ and so on. You can take a cue from my edit.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I will post my working asap

Answer (score 2):

One the one hand
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{{n^2  + n + 2k}}}  \le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{{n^2 }}}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{n}}  = \int_0^1 {x\, dx}  = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
On the other hand
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{{n^2  + n + 2k}}}  \ge \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{{n^2  + 3n}}} & = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{k/n}}{{1 + \frac{3}{n}}}}  \ge \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{n}\left( {1 - \frac{3}{n}} \right)} \\ & = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{n}}  - \frac{3}{n}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{n}} ,
\end{align*}
i.e.,
\begin{align*}
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{{n^2  + n + 2k}}} & \ge \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{n}}  - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{3}{n}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{k}{n}} \\ & = \int_0^1 {x\, dx}  - 0 \cdot \int_0^1 {x\, dx}  = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
Thus, by the squeeze theorem, the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: Use sandwich theorem. Put $k=n$ and $k=0$ in two cases and try to show your summation lies between these two. Then show that since limiting values of the other two summations is equal, this must have that value too.

Comment: Thanks....will try using sandwich on this

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is to use generalied harmonic numbers since
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac k{n^2+n+2k}\right)=\frac{1}{4} n \left((n+1) H_{\frac{1}{2} n (n+1)}-(n+1) H_{\frac{1}{2} n (n+3)}+2\right)$$
Now, using twice their asymptotics and continuing with Taylor series
$$S_n=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{3 n}+\frac{4}{3
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$